# cassandra-mesos health check fail when deploy with marathon

Tags: cassandra, iptables, mesos, mesosphere

I'm trying cassandra-mesos framework on my local mesos cluster. My cluster has:

- ip: 10.10.10.30 name: vcmms os: CentOs 6.7 {mesos-master, mesos-slave, marathon, zookeeper}
- ip: 10.10.10.31 name: vcmss1 os: CentOs 6.7 {mesos-slave}
- ip: 10.10.10.32 name: vcmss2 os: CentOs 6.7 {mesos-slave}

I'm using a restrictive security policy with iptables to avoid network attack.

The `iptable -L` on mesos-slaves:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)                                                                                                
target     prot opt source               destination                                                                     
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:apani1 flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN                    
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED                                   
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh                                                 
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/NONE                      
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:!FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN state NEW                    
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG/FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG   
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere                                                                        
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ita-agent                                           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpts:31000:32000                                        
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpts:afs3-fileserver:afs3-callback                      
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:7199                                                
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:9042                                                
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:apani1                                              

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)                                                                                            
target     prot opt source               destination                                                                     

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)                                                                                             
target     prot opt source               destination                                                                     

Chain DOCKER (0 references)                                                                                              
target     prot opt source               destination
```

my app.json:

```
{
  "id": "/cassandra/dev-test",
  "instances": 1,
  "cpus": 0.5,
  "mem": 512,
  "ports": [
    0
  ],
  "uris": [
    "http://mypublicstorage/cassandra-mesos-0.2.0-1.tar.gz",
    "http://mypublicstorage/jre-7u76-linux-x64.tar.gz"
  ],
  "env": {
    "MESOS_ZK": "zk://10.10.10.30:2181/mesos",
    "JAVA_OPTS": "-Xms256m -Xmx256m",
    "CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME": "dev-test",
    "CASSANDRA_ZK": "zk://10.10.10:2181/cassandra-mesos",
    "CASSANDRA_NODE_COUNT": "3",
    "CASSANDRA_RESOURCE_CPU_CORES": "2.0",
    "CASSANDRA_RESOURCE_MEM_MB": "2048",
    "CASSANDRA_RESOURCE_DISK_MB": "2048",
    "CASSANDRA_HEALTH_CHECK_INTERVAL_SECONDS": "60",
    "CASSANDRA_ZK_TIMEOUT_MS": "10000"
  },
  "cmd": "$(pwd)/jre*/bin/java $JAVA_OPTS -classpath cassandra-mesos-framework.jar io.mesosphere.mesos.frameworks.cassandra.framework.Main",
  "healthChecks": [
    {
      "gracePeriodSeconds": 120,
      "intervalSeconds": 30,
      "maxConsecutiveFailures": 0,
      "path": "/health/cluster",
      "portIndex": 0,
      "protocol": "HTTP",
      "timeoutSeconds": 5
    },
    {
      "gracePeriodSeconds": 120,
      "intervalSeconds": 30,
      "maxConsecutiveFailures": 3,
      "path": "/health/process",
      "portIndex": 0,
      "protocol": "HTTP",
      "timeoutSeconds": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

After submit app on marathon the framework is registered but health check failed. When I access to the page stats:"http://vcmms.domain:31329/health/cluster/report" the result it's:

```
{
  "healthy": false,
  "results": [
    {
      "name": "nodeCount",
      "ok": true,
      "expected": 3,
      "actual": 3
    },
    {
      "name": "seedCount",
      "ok": true,
      "expected": 2,
      "actual": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "allHealthy",
      "ok": false,
      "expected": [
        true,
        true,
        true
      ],
      "actual": [
        true
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "operatingModeNormal",
      "ok": false,
      "expected": [
        "NORMAL",
        "NORMAL",
        "NORMAL"
      ],
      "actual": [
        "NORMAL"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "lastHealthCheckNewerThan",
      "ok": false,
      "expected": [
        1443544996737,
        1443544996737,
        1443544996737
      ],
      "actual": [
        1443545237676
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "nodesHaveServerTask",
      "ok": true,
      "expected": [
        true,
        true,
        true
      ],
      "actual": [
        true,
        true,
        true
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**NOTE** 
When I disable all iptable restrictions all work fine, but I don't know the ports missing in my iptable rules that cause health check problems.